# Random Access Iterators using Indexes - Example

Tags: c++, iterator, c++98

I was trying to clarify my concept on iterators and while reading on `Random Access Iterators` the book states that these iterators can be used with indexes for instances `iterat[myIndex]`. Now I have used Random Access iterators with vectors in a trivial manner as such:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;

for(it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end() ; it++)
{
 std::cout << *it
}
```

I wanted to know how I would use an index with a Random Access iterator and when would I need to ? Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: If you, for example, want to implement your own generic binary search algorithm. You would take the parameters as `iterators` and you will have to access the elements in `O(1)`. So you need a random access iterator. How to use? `it = vec.begin(); end = vec.end(); newpos = it + ((end - it) / 2);`. In this case `newpos` will be halfway between `it` and `end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you need to look at the predecesdor and the successor of a position (assuming they are there). You could use

```
it[-1] // predecessor
it[0]  // current position same as *it
it[1]  // successor
```

Of course, when present you can also use other indices. Although the subscript operator needs to be defined I don't think I ever needed it in an algorithm. The positioning operations are a lotmore important.

Comment: Is there actually any difference between `it[n]` and `*(it+n)` or is the former just syntactic sugar?

Comment: +1 and I upvoted the question as well just for exposing what most people don't even know, that rand-access iterators expose `[]`.

Comment: @us2012 no, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). Terrific chart for each iterator type.

Comment: @us201233: The two expressions are semantically equivalent. Whether their implementation is the same is a different issue.

Comment: @DietmarKühl agreed. one could do the former without creating a temp-iterator. Hard-pressed to do that with the latter.